# JQuery: How to attach event to template objects?

Tags: jquery, templates

I have a template that generates images and I am binding it to div.

```
<script id="postTemplate" type="text/html">
<div class="post_1">
    <div class="postImage"><img src="${ImageUrl}" alt="Image"></div>
</div>
</script>
```

Then i bind the data

```
<script>
    $("#postTemplate").tmpl(clientData).appendTo("#imagesArea");
</script>
```

now, what i want is add an event handlers to that  i just created. something like

```
("template img").error(function() {});
```

Adding handlers to things like click seems to work, but error fires off before I can add the handler it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure what your selector "template img" is referencing since I dont see any template elements.

```
$(function(){

    $('template img').live({
      click: function() {
        // do something on click
      },
      error: function() {
        // do something on error
      }
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Careful with this answer, live has been depricated in favour of "on" http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 3):

```
$("template").on("error", "img", function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$("#postTemplate img").click(function() { alert('clicked'); });
```

must be called after you template has been added. Otherwise you will have to use **Live**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i get your problem but i guess you can store a reference to the generated object from template before appending it to the `#imagesArea` element, attaching events to that reference should work as:

```
var myGeneratedContent = $("#postTemplate").tmpl(clientData)
myGeneratedContent.appendTo('#imagesArea');
myGeneratedContent.click(function() { [...] });
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
("template img").bind("error",function() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .live(), which binds events even if element is created afterwards

```
$("#imagesArea img").live('click', function(){
   //do stuff here
});
```

Comment: You don't have to use live() ... there are many ways to attach events to elements after they are created/appended to the DOM. .live() is just handy.

Comment: You're right, I know that... Sorry, I've not chosen the right word... I've just edited my post, thank you